# How to customise a pyqt message box?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

pyqt4

```
msgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox()
msgBox.setText('Which type of answers would you like to view?')
msgBox.addButton(QtGui.QPushButton('Correct'), QtGui.QMessageBox.YesRole)
msgBox.addButton(QtGui.QPushButton('Incorrect'), QtGui.QMessageBox.NoRole)
msgBox.addButton(QtGui.QPushButton('Cancel'), QtGui.QMessageBox.RejectRole)

if msgBox == QtGui.QMessageBox.YesRole:
     Type = 1
      Doc()
elif msgBox == QtGui.QMessageBox.NoRole:
     Type = 0
     Bank()
else:
    ret = msgBox.exec_()
```

This displays a message box however when an option is clicked, nothing happens and the box closes. How do I get the next function to run?

Comment: Why do you compare msgBox which is a QMessaBox with the roles? what are you trying to do?

Comment: When the button is pushed, I want the if else statement to run, what should i be comparing it to? @eyllanesc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#exec) are reviewed:

> **int QMessageBox::exec()**
>
> Shows the message box as a modal dialog, blocking until the user closes it.
>
> When using a QMessageBox with standard buttons, this functions returns
> a StandardButton value indicating the standard button that was
> clicked. **When using QMessageBox with custom buttons, this function
> returns an opaque value; use clickedButton() to determine which button
> was clicked.**
>
> Note: The result() function returns also StandardButton value instead
> of QDialog::DialogCode
>
> Users cannot interact with any other window in the same application
> until they close the dialog, either by clicking a button or by using a
> mechanism provided by the window system.
>
> See also show() and result().

So as you recommend you must use `clickedButton()`, as I show below:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    msgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox()
    msgBox.setText('Which type of answers would you like to view?')
    correctBtn = msgBox.addButton('Correct', QtGui.QMessageBox.YesRole)
    incorrectBtn = msgBox.addButton('Incorrect', QtGui.QMessageBox.NoRole)
    cancelBtn = msgBox.addButton('Cancel', QtGui.QMessageBox.RejectRole)

    msgBox.exec_()

    if msgBox.clickedButton() == correctBtn:
        print("Correct")
    elif msgBox.clickedButton() == incorrectBtn:
        print("Incorrect")
    elif msgBox.clickedButton() == cancelBtn:
        print("Cancel")
```