# Switching Buttons in QMessageBox

Tags: python, qt5

I have this code:

```py
def initUI(self):
    mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

    # Temporary: Dialog Testing Button #
    self.buttonTest = button('Dialog Testing')
    self.buttonTest.clicked.connect(self.TestFile)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.buttonTest)

    self.setLayout(mainLayout)

# Connects to dialogTesting Button
def dialogMessage(self, message):
    dialog = QMessageBox(self)
    dialog.setWindowTitle('Sample Text')
    dialog.setText(message)

    dialog.show()

# Connects with dialogMessage class.
def TestFile(self):
    self.dialogMessage("When will non-OK buttons appear?")
    return
```

I get results like this:

[image: App with Popup]
[image: App with Button]

How can I change what buttons appear in the popup?

Comment: Please carefully note the [edit]s I made to the post. This is all the text that is needed to explain the problem clearly. Keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**; we want people to get to the question directly. The point is that other people should be able to read it quickly, and recognize whether this question is the same question that they have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the buttons by using an argument for the `buttons` parameter when you instantiate a QMessageBox. You use the [Standard Button](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#StandardButton-enum) constants. Here is a silly example:

```
dialog = QMessageBox(self, buttons=QMessageBox.Ok+QMessageBox.Save+QMessageBox.Yes )
```

If you don't like the choices for standard buttons, you can make your own using `addButton`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49156855/9705687) shows how to use `addButton`.